# Como evitar colisão de nomes de arquivos de upload

Tags: php, criptografia

Eu estou fazendo um site para *upload* de imagens, só que, quando faço o *upload* de dois arquivos com nomes iguais, o que havia antes some do diretório de arquivos.

Esse é o código que uso para o *upload*:

```
if(empty($_FILES)){
echo "<center><h1>Please, select the files</h1></center>";
}else{
    foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $key => $name){
        $_FILES['file']['size'][$key];
        if($_FILES['file']['error'][$key] == 0 && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key],"files/{$_FILES['file']['name'][$key]}")){     
            $link = "files/" . $_FILES['file']['name'][$key];
            $name = $_FILES['file']['name'][$key];
            $uploaded[] = $name;
            ?>

            <?php
            }
        }
    }
```

O nome com que o arquivo fica na pasta é definido pela linha `{$_FILES['file']['name'][$key]}`

Como fazer para fazer com que o nome do arquivo na pasta seja o seu nome encriptado, para evitar o erro que citei acima?

Comment: O que quer dizer com "seu nome criptografado"? Quero dizer: está assumindo que existe um nome criptografado para o arquivo? Onde teria sido criado?

Comment: Não, quero que o nome do arquivo na pasta seja uma o nome original do arquivo  criptografado

Comment: Desculpe, realmente não entendi. Bem, `md5`, `sha1` e `crypt` são funções do PHP de criptografia unidirecional, só que se for criptografar o nome do arquivo, para nomes iguais, tem resultados iguais, a não ser que adicione uma parte variável no nome, por exemplo a data/hora, só que isto por si já vai tornar o nome diferente. E tem mais: embora a chance seja realmente pequena, não há garantia de que o resultado de uma criptografia não vá se repetir com outros dados.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode resolver seu problema de uma maneira muito simples, basta adicionar uma sequência numérica caso o arquivo já exista:

```
if (empty($_FILES)) {
  echo "<center><h1>Please, select the files</center>";
} else {
   $number_add = 0;
    foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $key => $name) {
        $_FILES['file']['size'][$key];
        if ($_FILES['file']['error'][$key] == 0) { 
            if (!file_exists("files/" . $_FILES['file']['name'][$key])) {
               $link = "files/" . $_FILES['file']['name'][$key];
               $name = $_FILES['file']['name'][$key];
            } else {
               $link = "files/" . $number_add .'_'. $_FILES['file']['name'][$key];
               $name = $number_add .'_'. $_FILES['file']['name'][$key];
               $number_add++;
            }
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key], $link);
            $uploaded[] = $name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exatamente isso, resolveu o problema. Muito obrigado!